# Trying to delete only one row in table - Laravel

Tags: laravel-5.4

I am trying to update some users info. Here is my code :

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    $user = Auth::user();
    $user_id = Auth::user()->id;
    $arrRequest = $request->all();
    $contact = Contact::findOrFail($id)->where('user_id', $user_id);
    $validator = Validator::make($arrRequest, Contact::$rules);
    $content = null;

    if ($validator->fails()) {
        $status = 400;
        $content = $validator->errors();
    } else {
        $contact->update($arrRequest)->save();
        $status = 200;
    }

    return response($content, $status);
}
```

The main problem is that the request is applied to all rows in the table though I'm specifying the $id of the row for the request to be applied to. I'm struggling to see where is my mistake. 
The second problem (that just popped up) is that when I perform the request I'm now getting a message that says : `Call to a member function save() on integer`. But it was working just fine earlier (except it was updating all rows..) ! And Im retrieving an object ($contact) and not just an integer...
Thanks !

Comment: I've solved the second error, I was using ->save() but didn't need to, still really weird that I 've been able to perform the request earlier without any error.... but I still can't be able to perform the request on one particular row ! Its updating all tables...plz help :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `findOrFail()` method, which returns a Model or Collection.

After that you actually convert `$contact` into a Builder object by appending the `where()` method on the `findOrFail()` result. `findOrFail()` expects either an $id or array of $ids and will return a Model or Collection, not a Builder.

If you just want to make sure that the requested id is owned by the user, you can either check that after fetching the object, or use something other than `findOrFail()`.

```
$contact = Contact::findOrFail($id);
if ($contact->user_id != $user->id) {
    abort(403);
}
```

or

```
$contact = Contact::where('id', $id)
    ->where('user_id', $user->id)
    ->first();

if (! $contact) {
    abort(404);
}
```

Although I would not recommend the last one, just the `$id` should be enough to fetch the item you want.

---

The second error is caused by calling `save()` after `update()`, `update()` will return a boolean.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer. It explains a lot ! I've managed to get it working though, see my answer and please tell me if it seems ok ! (even if its working I may not be using the right thing)

Answer (score 0):

I've finally managed to make it work.. some weirds things happening though.
Here is my solution :

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {

    $user = Auth::user();
    $user_id = Auth::user()->id;
    $arrRequest = $request->all();
    $contact = Contact::where('user_id', $user_id)->find($id);
    $validator = Validator::make($arrRequest, Contact::$rules);
    $content = null;

    if ($validator->fails()) {
        $status = 400;
        $content = $validator->errors();
    } else {
        $contact->update($arrRequest);
        $contact->save();
        $status = 201;
    }

    return response($content, $status);
}
```

Thanks to Robert I can understand some parts of it. I guess if I make update() first then save() (not in a row), my save method is applying to the object and not the returned boolean? and thats why it works? still learning ahah !

Comment: You shouldn't combine the `find()`, `firstOrFail()`, `updateOrCreate()`, etc., methods with query builder methods like `where()`, etc.. The only reason this works is because you call `find($id)` on the Builder object. Right now it ignores the where completely. Turn on query log or install a package like debugbar so you can see the queries. Also right now you will get a 500 error when you try to update an id that does not exist. See my first example.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the feedback @Robert, I'll follow your example then ! About the error 500, yes of course, but I'll only update existing contacts (Im making sure of this in my app), but thanks again for the advices ! I think you may have misunderstood the purpose of my feature though, here the $id matches a contact in the contact_table, and the user_id is the user's own id. In my table I ll have multiples contacts depending of the current user logged in, these two ids are not refering to the same person, thats what I mean :D

Comment: I understand, but in your example the `where('user_id', $user_id)` will be ignored. If you would post to the action with an non-existing $id, `$contact` will be null. When your validation succeeds, you will call `update()` on null, which will trigger a 500 error.

Comment: Yes, Im fully aware of my mistakes now :D I'll work on that, and keep you in touch if I have troubles again :)